# How to create a new line in Android ?

Tags: android, newline

I am working on a project in android. I want to create a new  paragraph using `/n`. But I am  not getting results as expected.Is there any other way to create a new line?

My code is as follows

```
tv.setText("Some of the symptoms of cataract include:/n1.Cloudy, blurry or foggy vision/n2. Development of short-sightedness in older people/n3. Seeing colors differently./n3. Problems with glare during the day or night/n4. Double vision/n5. Sudden changes in prescription of glasses");
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `\n` instead. Your slash is in the wrong direction. It has to be a *back* slash.

Answer (score 5):

`\n`  Insert a newline in the text at this point.

hence, Use `\n` instead of `/n`

Answer (score 2):

Try this one out :)

```
System.getProperty("line.separator")
```

For example:

```
TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView.setText("Hello"+System.getProperty("line.separator")+"World!!!");
```